# SSIS 2016 system variable System::ErrorDescription missing?

Tags: ssis

Using SSIs 2016 trying to set an input parameter to a sql task to System::ErrorDescription, but that variable isnt listed.  Is this variable not used any longer?

I have sql task that, if it fails, I want to log the error desciption to a table.  Yes, I know I can enable logging, but I want also use this message in another task.

[Edit]
I think this variable is only visible within the context of an event handler such as OnError, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The `System::ErrorDescription` variable is not available for all components, specifically it is only in the `OnError`, `OnInformation`, and `OnWarning` event handlers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-2016